# Download a complete folder hierarchy in google drive api python

Tags: python, google-drive-api

How can I download a complete folder hierarchy using python Google drive api. Is it that I have query each files in the folder and then download that. But doing this way, folder hierarchy will be lost. Any way to make it in proper way. Thanks

Comment: You need to request the files with in each folder individually.  There is no way to get a full list in one request.

Comment: Thanks DalmTo for the supersonic reply. So that means I got to maintain the heirarchy in my end. Got it !

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22092402/python-google-drive-api-list-the-entire-drive-file-tree/22110005#22110005 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23324690/best-way-to-upload-a-directory-of-images-to-google-drive-in-python/23331227#23331227

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55989689/6498836 I have Answered This question Please Use the above link

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this using Google GAM.

```
gam all users show filelist >filelist.csv
gam all users show filetree >filetree.csv
```

I got all the answers from this site. I found it very useful.
https://github.com/jay0lee/GAM/wiki

Answer (score -1):

Default max results of query is 100. Must use pageToken/nextPageToken to repeat it.
see [Python Google Drive API - list the entire drive file tree](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22092402/python-google-drive-api-list-the-entire-drive-file-tree/24543817#24543817)