# Python: How do download entire folder from Google Drive

Tags: python

I use this code to download Google drive files from the file id, and give a file it's own name

```
!pip install -U -q PyDrive

from google.colab import files
from pydrive.auth import GoogleAuth
from pydrive.drive import GoogleDrive
from google.colab import auth
from oauth2client.client import GoogleCredentials
import os
import sys


auth.authenticate_user()
gauth = GoogleAuth()
gauth.credentials = GoogleCredentials.get_application_default()
drive = GoogleDrive(gauth)

def downloadFiles(googleID, fileName):
    print("Downloading ", fileName)
    toDl = drive.CreateFile({'id': googleID})
    toDl.GetContentFile(fileName)
```

`downloadFiles("0B7Mdz82xyAxcMzJYOFhfg5gfMnp6Tl9Cei00U3BKTGNN","news.npy")`

Where the string of numbers for the first argument in `downloadFiles` is the google drive file ID, which is obtained by right clicking the file and selecting get share link.

I tried doing with with a share link ID for a google drive folder, this is the error I got

`downloadFiles("1kdNDfvg2zyyXYYrcXVnuuhIOnSLgtrnE","dlFolder")`

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
FileNotDownloadableError                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-4-b59b205fcc37> in <module>()
      1 
      2 
----> 3 downloadFiles("1kdNDfvg2zyyXYYrcXVnuuhIOnSLgtrnE","news")

<ipython-input-2-cbfb11eb1c03> in downloadFiles(googleID, fileName)
      2     print("Downloading ", fileName)
      3     toDl = drive.CreateFile({'id': googleID})
----> 4     toDl.GetContentFile(fileName)

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pydrive/files.py in GetContentFile(self, filename, mimetype, remove_bom)
    208                     type(self.content) is not io.BytesIO or \
    209                     self.has_bom == remove_bom:
--> 210       self.FetchContent(mimetype, remove_bom)
    211     f = open(filename, 'wb')
    212     f.write(self.content.getvalue())

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pydrive/files.py in _decorated(self, *args, **kwargs)
     41     if not self.uploaded:
     42       self.FetchMetadata()
---> 43     return decoratee(self, *args, **kwargs)
     44   return _decorated
     45 

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pydrive/files.py in FetchContent(self, mimetype, remove_bom)
    263     else:
    264       raise FileNotDownloadableError(
--> 265         'No downloadLink/exportLinks for mimetype found in metadata')
    266 
    267     if mimetype == 'text/plain' and remove_bom:

FileNotDownloadableError: No downloadLink/exportLinks for mimetype found in metadata
```

Comment: look at this , it may help https://gist.github.com/revolunet/9507070
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39003409/how-to-download-specific-google-drive-folder-using-python

Comment: https://github.com/vikynandha/google-drive-backup/blob/master/drive.py

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to download specific Google Drive folder using Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39003409/how-to-download-specific-google-drive-folder-using-python)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Found the answer

```
!pip install -U -q PyDrive
import os
from pydrive.auth import GoogleAuth
from pydrive.drive import GoogleDrive
from google.colab import auth
from oauth2client.client import GoogleCredentials

# 1. Authenticate and create the PyDrive client.
auth.authenticate_user()
gauth = GoogleAuth()
gauth.credentials = GoogleCredentials.get_application_default()
drive = GoogleDrive(gauth)

# choose a local (colab) directory to store the data.
local_download_path = ''
try:
    os.makedirs(local_download_path)
except: pass

# 2. Auto-iterate using the query syntax
#    https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/web/search-parameters
file_list = drive.ListFile(
    {'q': "'1m4t_k5N7-W3saafdfddfdWCqfc1D0xHmc20r' in parents"}).GetList()  #use your own folder ID here

for f in file_list:
    # 3. Create & download by id.
    print('title: %s, id: %s' % (f['title'], f['id']))
    fname = f['title']
    print('downloading to {}'.format(fname))
    f_ = drive.CreateFile({'id': f['id']})
    f_.GetContentFile(fname)
```

Comment: doesnt help for downloading directories recursively.